# Migration tool customised fields

Tags: magento2, migration

A bit confused with the data migration tool.

As far as I know it will **scan** the **whole database**, including any new data that any extra modules have added in Magento 1 db, that is why we can add/ignore fields on the mapping config files so that all the fields are mapped. 
But I'm not sure whether it creates or not the data schema of new fields in the Magento2 database or they have to be created manually beforehand? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Database schema must exists first. The tool migrate only the data. You can handle schema exceptions within the mapping files e.g. different data field or table name.

**Best practice:**

In front of running the migration you should cleanup your database. (Of course on a copy not on the production DB.) Make sure your data are clean.

There are some vendor extensions which remove foreign key constraints between tables and add a lot of messy data. For example millions of old values for several attributes in the "catalog_product_entity_*" tables.

Automate the migration process in order to run it several times and be able to improve the result each time you repeat it.

- Import M1 database dump
- Import your M2 database schema
- Run your M1 clean up script
- Run the migration